# Aggregation with multiple conditions javascript/mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Im trying to use aggregation on my mongoose .

The ideal script, would sum up all crime.amount and heavy_crime amount the last 100 days, and only get the results relevant with the userid.

(today: `todate` )
( 100 days ago: `fromdate`)

model:

```
time: Number,
    userid : String,

  crime: {
        cash: {type: Number, default: 0},
        amount: { type: Number, default: 0}
    },
    heavy_crime: {
        cash: {type: Number, default: 0},
        amount: { type: Number, default: 0}
    },
```

Attempting code:

```
function checkCrimeRating(userid) {
    var todate = new Date();
    var fromdate = new Date();
    var lastfive = new Date();
    var MainDate = date.getDate();

    fromdate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    todate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    lastfive.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    lastfive.setDate(MainDate - 5);
    fromdate.setDate(MainDate - 100);


    return dailyStats.aggregate(
        { $group: {
            _id: "$time" : $gte {fromdate.getTime()}, $lte: {todate.getTime()},
            total:       { $sum: { $add: ["$crime.amount", "$heavycrime.amount"] } },
        }}
    ).then(function (numberO))
}
```

*So how can i make the aggregation only work sum up the last 100 days, with the right userid?*

```
numberO Would ideally return number of crime and heavycrime the last 100 days.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `$match` stage.

Move your date comparison to match stage followed by `$group` to sum crimes.

```
dailyStats.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "user": userid,
      "time": {
        "$gte": fromdate.getTime(),
        "$lte": todate.getTime()
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "total": {
        "$sum": {
          "$add": [
            "$crime.amount",
            "$heavycrime.amount"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```